# word break a long sentence by word

Tags: css, word-break

> "Subject to 10% service charge per room per night. Any cancellation or
>   amendments can be made 2 days prior to arrival. Otherwise, one nights’
>   room rate will be levied. The first night guarantee is required at
>   time of reservation and one night room rental will be charged to the
>   credit card provided in the event of no show, late cancellation or
>   amendment. If any dispute arises, Hotel Rainbow Hong Kong reserves the
>   final decision."

i use the css properties "word-break:break-all", but it did not do well.
there are still some word being break up.

Comment: `word-break` property is not supported in `Opera`. couldn't you use php `explode()` to get each work as an array item? http://uk1.php.net/explode

Comment: what i want just display in html.

Comment: You should explain that in your question so we can actually help you rather than guessing.

Comment: Show an actual example (HTML and CSS) that demonstrates the issue, describe what you want, and tell us how the results differ from that. What you are doing is telling browsers that th ey m ay bre ak wor ds arb itrari ly. Is that what you want? If not, what then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**** You need 'word-wrap' property ****

Use this one

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Answer (score -1):

Visit [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3%5fpr%5fword-break.asp)

```
p{word-break:break-all;}
```

Comment: break-all will break up a word, for example "will" will be breaked into 'w' + 'ill'.thanks for your help.